# Schema Registry with Spring Kafka and Avro

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

Created Spring Kafka producer and consumer applications that are connect to the schema registry. Created a schema group with forward compatibility (avro) and uploaded a avro schema. When I have single version both applications are working fine.

Now added a new filed to schema, so the version got increased to 2. Producer application using version 2 to send the message and consumer still using old version (version 1). while consuming the message consumer application throwing the error. I am uisng avroSpecificRecord.

Do I need to specify any version number on consumer side? how consumer application know which version of schema to use ?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error deserializing Avro message.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 cannot be cast to class com.test.model.Alternates (org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 and com.test.model.Alternates are in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @1de0aca6)
```

---

I am using Azure EventHub Schema registry libraries, but eventually those are also using apache avro libraries.

**Schema V1:** - using by consumer

```
   {
   "type" : "record",
    "namespace" : "com.test",
    "name" : "Employee",
    "fields" : [
        { "name" : "firstName" , "type" : "string" },
        { "name" : "age", "type" : "int" }
    ]
}
```

**Schema V2:** - using by producer

```
   {
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "com.test",
    "name": "Employee",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "firstName",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "middleName",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
               ],
            "default" : null
             
        },
        {
            "name": "age",
            "type": "int"
        }
    ]
}
```

When producer sent a message, message appended with version 2 ID. So consumer expecting version 2 schema while deserialize that message.

```
  ERROR: 

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @1de0aca6; java.lang.Integer is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.aa.opshub.test.Employee.put(Employee.java:110) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.setField(GenericData.java:816) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar!/:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:139) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar!/:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:247) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar!/:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readRecord(SpecificDatumReader.java:123) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar!/:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar!/:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar!/:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar!/:1.9.2]
    at com.azure.data.schemaregistry.avro.AvroSchemaRegistryUtils.decode(AvroSchemaRegistryUtils.java:131) ~[azure-data-schemaregistry-avro-1.0.0-beta.4.jar!/:?]
    at com.azure.data.schemaregistry.avro.SchemaRegistryAvroSerializer.lambda$deserializeAsync$1(SchemaRegistryAvroSerializer.java:101) ~[azure-data-schemaregistry-avro-1.0.0-beta.4.jar!/:?]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:169) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1784) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.subscribe(MonoCallable.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3987) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3972) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1678) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
    at com.azure.data.schemaregistry.avro.SchemaRegistryAvroSerializer.deserialize(SchemaRegistryAvroSerializer.java:50) ~[azure-data-schemaregistry-avro-1.0.0-beta.4.jar!/:?]
    at com.microsoft.azure.schemaregistry.kafka.avro.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:66) ~[azure-schemaregistry-kafka-avro-1.0.0-beta.4.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1365) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3400(Fetcher.java:130) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1596) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1700(Fetcher.java:1432) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:684) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:635) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1283) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1237) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1210) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1238) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1133) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1054) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    ... 3 more
2021.06.02 23:05:56,821 org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1 DEBUG com.azure.core.util.logging.ClientLogger.performLogging(ClientLogger.java:335) - Cache hit for schema id 'eb3549cd9b544e3a89b8d693275a502f'
2021.06.02 23:05:56,821 org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1 ERROR com.azure.core.util.logging.ClientLogger.performLogging(ClientLogger.java:350) - Error deserializing Avro message.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error deserializing Avro message.
```

When middle name is placed at the end of schema v2 and I regenerated classes at Producer applications. No changes made at Consumer (still using schema v1), getting below error at consumer application .

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index: 2
```

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace? Are you able to show both schemas? Consumers use the ID embedded in the message to deserialize data, but you still need to update your SpecificRecord class dependencies, if you use those

Comment: added schemas with error trace.

Comment: So, you're using `SpecificDatumReader`... Did you regenerate your `com.test.Employee` java file with the newer schema? Also, your package doesn't match in the stacktrace `com.aa.opshub.test.Employee`

Comment: Yes.I regenerates the Java classes in producer application using schema V2. Did not make any changes at consumer side. Namespace in schema is same as what showing in stacktrace. I am trying something different way, so pasted schemas from there.But actual applications has same namespace as what in stacktrace.

Comment: Basically, the issue is that Avro deserializes fields by order rather than name. By adding the name in the _middle of the schema_, it's thinking its an int (the old field order). If you'd placed the middle name at the end, you should expect a different error

Comment: Ok.Will try by placing field at the end. But in real time it’s not the case right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Avro libraries are still used here. Kafka isn't introducing any difference in how data is represented or parsed

Comment: Placed middle name at the end of schema v2 and regenarated classes at Producer applicatons. No changes made at Consumer (still using schema v1).  getting below error at consumer application . Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index: 2

Comment: Right. That's what I expected when I said "different error". And you **are required** to update the Consumer model classes. So, I guess question would be 1) If you are able to look at the Registry server request logs, which ID/schema is the consumer actually getting? 2) Do you really **need** a specific record type? You should be able to consume `GenericRecord` just as easily.

Comment: This is POC. In actual applications, I can not control consumers when they want to move to new schema. I am data producer and have multiple consumers. Based on one or two consumer requirements I will add new fields to schema on producer side and increase the version. I thought Schema registry with Forward compatibility will support this POC use case when I upgrade schema to V2 on producer side but consumer with schema V1. Here consumer receiving the payload with V2 schema ID and that is causing the issue.

Comment: I've never used forward compatibility, only full (with and without transitive), and backwards (with and without transitive). Since you're "adding an optional field", that's what backwards mode, at a minimum, is stated to be used for - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/avro.html#compatibility-types

Comment: Even if I make new field as mandatory, if will be same case. looks like with schema registry there is no option for consumer to use specific schema version they want to use when producer continuously updating the schema. I thought Forward compatibility works. Please reply here if you come across this scenario in future.

Comment: I used to work in an environment that app teams added new nullable fields all the time. However, I was on the infrastructure team, so I'm not sure what order consumers upgraded in, but of course producers were the ones deploying any schema changes, and only rarely did the we get complaints about active consumers dying with schema exceptions. But, like I said, we didn't use forward mode, only full or backward

Comment: I am running into the same issue right now. Is there any way to fix this? I cannot control the producer and the consumer cannot update avdl files based on producer changes